# How to properly use language format in Notepad ++

Tags: php, notepad++

I have this situation trying to disable a sequence into a .php file (the black commented lines, back-to-top text button);
I've read about block commenting in notepad ++ and setting the language of the file but the comment it looks like is not implemented properly.

[image]

What I've done :

-File / Open the .php file, 

(already it looks like it is viewed in php language judging by the colors) 

-Selection between 355-359 lines and Block Comment  (ctrl+shift+Q).After that, I've added the text but it doesn't look like the other existing comments.

Any thoughts? Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP comments only work when you are inside PHP mode (between `<?php` and `?>`).

When you are outputting HTML, you need HTML comments which take the form `<!-- comment which does not include two adjacent hyphens -->`.

The PHP within an HTML comment will still execute and the results will be output to the browser. It looks like your PHP only outputs data and doesn't do any significant processing, so that will probably be sufficient. You might, especially in other cases, be better off simply deleting the code and then restoring it from your version control system's history later.

Comment: I was thinking (and installed) Visual SVN but it will take another 2-3 days to understand how it works ... that's why I try to go the simple way (I'm not a coder, I make just a few modifications) Thanks,

Comment: Regarding the above mentioned, will be      <!--> comment for html <span >mmmm </span> <--> OR      <!-- comment for html
        <span >mmmm </span>
     --> ? I suppose that there is a difference between <!--> <--> and <!-- ... -->

Comment: @typo_ — It's the difference between `/* comment */` and `/*> comment */`. An extra  (nonsensical) character in the body of the comment.

Comment: at this point I'm confused :D; You mean that in the above situation will be enough to use `/*> comment <span> ...... </span> */ ` instead of `<!--> comment for html <span >mmmm </span> <-->` OR `<!-- comment for html <span >mmmm </span> -->` ?

Comment: @typo_ — No. I was demonstrating the difference by way of the equivalent in PHP. You need to use HTML syntax. There is no `>` as part of the opening part of an HTML comment. If you put a `>` there then it is just a character that is part of the comment text.

Comment: Got that, in the end will be <!-- comment for html <span >mmmm </span> -->  am I right?

Answer (score 0):

For that part of code you should comment using:

`<!-- your comment -->`

As you are using `html` (you closed the part of your php code by `?>` )